# How do I get my layout component to remain static in Next13 app folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, app-folder

I am trying to create a layout component that fetches its own data, I have tried adding the cache: 'force-cache' to the fetch but every time I update my CMS content and refresh my page the new content is loaded. Here is an example of my code:

```
const getLayoutData = async () => {
 const response = await fetch(
    `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/${
      process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID
    }/environments/${
      process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT || "master"
    }/entries/${fieldId}?access_token=${process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    {
      cache: "force-cache",
    }
  );

  const {entryTitle, ...headerData} = await response.json();

  return { headerData };
}

export default async function Layout() {
 const data = await getLayoutData();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`getStaticProps()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) function to fetch data at build time and make it available to your component as a prop. This way, the data will be pre-rendered on the server and will not change when the user refreshes the page:

```
import getLayoutData from './getLayoutData';

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = await getLayoutData();
  return { props: { data } };
}

export default function Layout({ data }) {
  // Use data in your component
  ...
}
```

Alternatively you could use [`getServerSideProps()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props), it runs on the server at request time instead of build time. I would recommend that if you have dynamic data that changes frequently:

```
import getLayoutData from './getLayoutData';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const data = await getLayoutData();
  return { props: { data } };
}

export default function Layout({ data }) {
  // Use data in your component
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Next.js automatically does static fetches. This means that the data will be fetched at build time, cached, and reused on each request. As a developer, you have control over how the static data is cached and revalidated.

Refer to the docs - https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals

Also, this will work in production mode. So, make sure you are using `next build && next start` and not `next dev`.

In case you are fetching data from same URL anywhere else, the cache might be getting updated. As Next.js also does request deduplication built into the `fetch` function itself.